# How to ignore error "That Name is already taken. Try a different one."

Tags: excel, vba

My VBA Statement is below.

[image: Error Highlighted in Yellow]

As I am using jet reports The work book will update SomeTimes the name in Cell "B3" is the same and some times it is different.

What do I add to this string to ignore "That Name is already taken. Try a different one."

```
Sub RenameSheet()

Dim rs As Worksheet

For Each rs In Sheets
rs.Name = rs.Range("B3")
Next rs

End Sub
```

Not sure how to fix

Comment: Choose a different name. You can't have multiple worksheets with the same name.

Comment: What is the cause of the name clash? (1) Multiple sheets have the same value in B3. (2) All sheets have distinct values in B3, but another sheet (`shtClash`) currently has the name `rs.Range("B3")` and hasn't been renamed to `shtClass.Range("B3")` yet. (3) Different cause (please explain).

Comment: Correction: I meant `shtClash.Range("B3")` above.

Answer (score 1):

### Rename Worksheets

**Short**

```vb
Sub RenameWorksheetsShort()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, NewName As String
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        NewName = CStr(ws.Range("B3").Value)
        If ws.Name <> NewName Then
            On Error Resume Next
                ws.Name = NewName
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

**In More Detail**

```vb
Sub RenameWorksheets()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim wsCount As Long: wsCount = wb.Worksheets.Count
    Dim Arr(): ReDim Arr(1 To wsCount)

    Dim ws As Worksheet, w As Long, ErrNumber As Long, NewName As String
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        NewName = CStr(ws.Range("B3").Value)
        If ws.Name <> NewName Then
            On Error Resume Next
                ws.Name = NewName
                ErrNumber = Err.Number
            On Error GoTo 0
            If ErrNumber <> 0 Then
                w = w + 1
                Arr(w) = """" & ws.Name & """ to """ & NewName & """"
            End If
        End If
    Next ws

    If w = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Worksheet names updated.", vbInformation
    Else
        If w < wsCount Then
            ReDim Preserve Arr(1 To w)
        End If
        MsgBox "Could not rename the following worksheets:" & vbLf & vbLf _
           & Join(Arr, vbLf), vbCritical
    End If
    
End Sub
```